# Angular Service worker with FCM push notification

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, firebase, progressive-web-apps

In my web app(using Angular4) I am using `"@angular/service-worker": "^1.0.0-beta.16"` for generating service worker and also using `firebase-messaging-sw.js` for FCM push notification, angular/service-worker creates `worker-basic.min.js` only in production build. Now, how to use these 2 service-workers together??

Answer (score 6):

I can respond about using simultaneously :

- **sw-precache Service Worker**  (whose aim is to cache static ressources) implemented as `service-worker.js`. See https://coryrylan.com/blog/fast-offline-angular-apps-with-service-workers
- **Firebase Messaging Service Worker** (whose aim is to handle web push notifications) implemented as `firebase-messaging-sw.js`.

**1. Development:**  in `src` directory:

- I create an empty file named `service-worker.js`. The real one will be generated after the build process but this file has to exist (even empty) to avoid error message while serving with `ng serve`.
- I create a file named `firebase-messaging-sw.js` whose content is: (add `https://` before both `www`, stakoverflow limits me in number of links!)
  `importScripts('www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/3.9.0/firebase-app.js');
  importScripts('www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/3.9.0/firebase-messaging.js');
  firebase.initializeApp({
  'messagingSenderId': 'xxxxxxxxxxxx' // replace by yours!
  });
  const messaging = firebase.messaging();`
- I create a file named `global-sw.js`. This is THE Service Worker you
  have to register in `index.html` (ask me how if needed). Content of `global-sw.js` is:
  `importScripts('service-worker.js');
  importScripts('firebase-messaging-sw.js');`

**2. Update of .angular-cli.json:** To have those files included in my future `dist` directory (generated with the production build process), I update `.angular-cli.json` this way : 
 [.angular-cli.json - extract](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AJZLg.jpg)

**3. Production build:** I run `ng build -prod` then I generate `service-worker.js`. For me, this one can only be generated after the build process.

Comment: I am not sure if creating an empty service-worker.js is the best solution but it is the only solution for me so far.. so thank you.. also it would be better to create a folder and put the three service worker scripts in there.. don't you think? or service workers have to served from root?

Comment: In `src`directory, `service-worker.js` is empty just to avoid an error message in console during development. But after build time, it is actually generated (see my step #3) in the `dist` folder. Anyway, it could not be generated at another time because it references, among other files, your bundles (made at build time).

Comment: ya i get that. i just think it is annoying having a file to get rid of an error. But it works!.

Comment: not working, after running 'ng build --prod' here is my index.html in dist folder '<body>
  <app-root></app-root>
  <script>
    if ('serviceWorker' in navigator) {
      navigator.serviceWorker
        .register('./global-sw.js')
        .then(function () { console.log('Service Worker Registered'); });
    }
  </script>
.....
<script type="text/javascript" src="sw-register.6819cd2c5fa25470ecf2.bundle.js"></script>
........'

Comment: while running in chrome, in application tab its still showing 2 service workers

Comment: Yes, same for me. `global-sw.js`is not an effective service worker. It's a file making imports of files implementing service-workers functionnalities. In Chrome Dev Tools 'Application' tab you visualize the functionnality of static assets precaching and the functionnality of push messaging. You can see that they have different scopes.

Comment: @Debu @MurWade - In fact `global-sw.js`, though not uncorrect, is not needed. If you name (exactly) `firebase-messaging-sw.js`the js file that handles push messaging (see my detailed answer above), then you don't have to register any push messaging service worker. It's written here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/js/receive. You handle sw-precache classically without special connection to push messaging service worker (via what I called `global-sw.js` for instance).

Comment: @OlivierLourme my push notification is working fine, but my local cashing is not working, i.e `firebase-messaging-sw.js` is working, but `worker-basic.min.js` is not working

Comment: @Debu - I can't help you, I use `sw-precache` (to cache static assets) along with `firebase-messaging.js` and it works fine. I didn't have the time to get through the one you mention. Sorry.

Answer (score 1):

Just add to angular.json the file you want the compiler to know about.

```
"assets": [
    "src/favicon.ico",
    "src/assets",
    "src/firebase-messaging-sw.js", // add this one
    "src/manifest.json" // this one also 
]
```

Credits to https://medium.com/mighty-ghost-hack/angular-8-firebase-cloud-messaging-push-notifications-cc80d9b36f82

Answer (score 0):

The SWPrecacheWebpackPlugin wrapper for the swprecache module's API has an option called "importScripts" which can be used to import for example "firebase-messaging-sw.js" in this case.