# How can we use FCM Service Worker with a existing Service Worker?

Tags: angular, firebase-cloud-messaging, service-worker, angular-service-worker

We are creating a PWA web app and currently, we are using sw-precache library for generating service worker file, which is working as expected. And now we have added FCM service worker for listening incoming message while it's offline, but it's overwriting our existing service worker.

So how can we integrate the firebase service worker with an existing service worker which is generated using sw-precache?

I'd tried several ways, current code :

```
if ('serviceWorker' in navigator) {
    navigator.serviceWorker.register('/service-worker.js').then((registration) => {
        console.log('Service Worker registered');
    }).catch(function (err) {
        console.log('Service Worker registration failed: ', err);
    });

    navigator.serviceWorker.register('/firebase-messaging-sw.js', { scope: '/firebase-cloud-messaging-push-scope' }).then(function (registration) {
         console.log('f Service Worker registered');
     }).catch(function (err) {
         console.log('f Service Worker registration failed: ', err);
     });
}
```

---

**UPDATE 1:** I'd tried `useServiceWorker(registration)` as well, its registering the main service worker but when I'd initializing firebase within my service it's expecting the `firebase-messaging-sw.js` to load so it's throwing some error in console.

Service code:

```
import * as firebase from 'firebase';
import { isPlatformBrowser } from '@angular/common';

@Injectable()
export class MessagingService {   
  messaging;

  constructor(
    @Inject(PLATFORM_ID) private _platformId: Object, ) {
    if (isPlatformBrowser(this._platformId)) {
      var config = {
        messagingSenderId: "XXXXXXXX"
      };

      firebase.initializeApp(config);
      this.messaging = firebase.messaging();
    }
  }

  //  ......

}
```

Error in console :

[image]

[image]

Tried the following answer as well, but no success:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/46171748/3037257

---

**UPDATE 2:** Finally adding `useServiceWorker(registration)` and an empty `firebase-messaging-sw.js` file both service workers are getting registered but caching is not working.

Comment: /service-worker.js the provided path is incorrect. I have provided path as   `${process.env.PUBLIC_URL}/firebase-messaging-sw.js` with firebase-messaging-sw.js in public folder of create react application.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In order to take all control of sw.js and push notification `useServiceWorker` is very useful.

See this documentation [useServiceWorker(registration)](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.messaging.Messaging)

```
   /------index.html------/
    var config = {
        apiKey: "xxxxxxxxxxxx",
        authDomain: "xxxxxxxxxxxx",
        databaseURL: "xxxxxxxxxxxx",
        projectId: "xxxxxxxxxxxx",
        storageBucket: "xxxxxxxxxxxx",
        messagingSenderId: "xxxxxxxxxxxx"
    };
    firebase.initializeApp(config);
    var messaging = firebase.messaging();

navigator.serviceWorker.register('service-worker.js')
.then((registration) => {
  messaging.useServiceWorker(registration);


});
```

Comment: I'd tried this one as well.... but when i'd tried to initialize firebase within my service.... it's showing service worker registartion failed.....

Comment: 1st, SW dont have access to your dom, so if you want to initialize firebase in SW then you should import all firebase dependency at starting of SW. 2nd you no need to initialize firebase in SW, write above code in index.html.

Comment: Can you share screenshot of your file structure in project directory...!

Comment: in production both service-worker would be in same directory, `/dist` folder

Comment: `firebase-messaging-sw.js` is mandatory file for FCM push notification, i think  your problem root is mime-type `text/html`, try to remove that error

Comment: I'd removed `firebase-messaging-sw.js` file since `messaging.useServiceWorker(registration);` is added

Comment: also what would be the content?

Comment: both service workers are getting registered but caching is not working

Comment: Are you aware about, SW only register on `localhost` or `https`...?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/163313/discussion-between-pranav-c-balan-and-tushar-acharekar).

Comment: I cannot see your discussion in chat. How did you solve that problem? I'm in the same situation except that I have a polymer project that generates the service-worker.js in build time and I need to integrate firebase-messaging-sw.js.

Comment: Same here, but i'm developing a PWA with react. Can you provide some more infos?

Answer (score 3):

In app.module.ts or you can put the snippet starting with constructor(sw...) into a service file that you will initialise when it reaches certain lazy loaded feature module.

```js
import * as firebase from 'firebase';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    ServiceWorkerModule.register('/ngsw-worker.js', {enabled: environment.production}),
    AppRoutingModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule {
  constructor(swPush: SwPush) {
    if (swPush.isEnabled) {
      navigator.serviceWorker
        .ready
        .then((registration) => firebase.messaging().useServiceWorker(registration));
    }
  }
}
```

In angular-cli.json make sure you have firebase-messaging-sw.js

```js
{
  "apps": [
    {
      "root": "src",
      "outDir": "dist",
      "assets": [
        "assets",
        "favicon.ico",
        "manifest.json",
        "firebase-messaging-sw.js"
      ],
      "index": "index.html",
      "main": "main.ts",
      "environmentSource": "environments/environment.ts",
      "environments": {
        "dev": "environments/environment.ts",
        "prod": "environments/environment.prod.ts"
      },
      "serviceWorker": true
    }
  ]
}
```